# Fresh POSTMAN 4.9.3, env variable bug or feature?

Tags: parsing, environment-variables, response, updates, postman

My requests return BigInteger id. I use these lines to extract them from response:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", data.id);
```

I updated Postman App to version 4.9.3 and caught a problem with environmental variables. 
For example, I receive id="9141989209013199260" and expect app to save "9141989209013199260", but i'm getting "9141989209013199000" instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Update wasn't to blame

Comment: I also encountered this issue! Please explain how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '{ "id": 9146756954251460484, "name" : "test" }'; 
    str = str.replace(/\d{19}/, '"$&"');
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    alert(obj.id);
```

Done!